# Display Android Dialog Box during animation of another view?

Tags: android, animation

I have a ImageView on which i have applied a motion animation.
During the animation I have to display a Dialog Popup, but when i do so, the animation gets hanged for few milliseconds till dialog is appeared.
Thus it gives overall sluggish Ui experience.
How can i display a dialog popup during animation of any view without sluggishness?

Answer (score 0):

Did you used to show the popup on another thread (runOnUIThread)?

Comment: runOnUiThread is used to update view/UI from non-UI threads but I am displaying Dialog Box and Animated View in an Activity, thus it wont make any difference i guess.